# Adding a service layer to my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Currently, I have a controller method that includes a try/catch statement for sending emails that loops through a db list:

```
try
            {
                // MailSender object declaration
                MailSender objMail = new MailSender();

                // Set SMTP server address
                objMail.Host = "smtp.test.com";

                // Sender's address
                objMail.From = "test@test.com";

                // Subject
                objMail.Subject = surveyprogrammodel.Subject;

                // HTML format?
                objMail.IsHTML = true;

                //Send to Mail Queue
                objMail.Queue = true;
                objMail.QueuePath = Server.MapPath("~\\MailQueue\\");

                     foreach (var item in EmailList)
                        {

                            //  Create dynamic link to the take the Survey
                            var SurveyLink = strUrl + UrlContent + "SurveyResponse/Create?MemberId=" + item.PersonModels.MemberId + "&ProgramId=" + item.ProgramId;

                            // Recipient's address
                            objMail.AddAddress(item.PersonModels.Email);

                            // Body
                            objMail.Body = surveyprogrammodel.Body + "<br /><br />Please take the survey using the link below:<br /><br /><a href=\"" + SurveyLink + "\">" + SurveyLink + "<a/>";

                            // Send message
                            objMail.Send();

                            objMail.ResetAddresses();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write("An error occurred: <font color=red>"+ ex.Message + "</font>");
                    }
```

I am wondering how I could break this statement out into a sort of service, so that I could easily swap mailer implementations if I needed to.  Is there a good example that can explain the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In the most simplistic, non-complicated example, you can simply create an interface.

```
interface IEmailer
{
    void Send(List<Email> email);
}

class SimpleMailer : IEmailer
{
    void Send(List<Email> email)
    {
        //do work
    }
}

class ComplexMailer : IEmailer
{
    void Send(List<Email> email)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Usage

```
IEmailer mailer = new SimpleMailer();
```

Implementation change

```
IEmailer mailer = new ComplexMailer();
```

And then if you want a look-up style implementation, you can implement a Service Locator Pattern / use a DI framework (StructureMap, Ninject, etc).  There's an example right on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921142.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  And what does the List<Email> email contain?  Would that be the email object parameters for sending?

Comment: Yes - It would be your email object, which would probably consist of a subject, body, email addr, etc.